# Laravel 5 Generated .txt not redirecting to view

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel web app that generates a formatted .txt and then has the browser download it, and refreshing the form after everything is done, the .txt is generated correctly but I'm not getting a redirect, how can I make a redirect and also have the file downloaded? I wouldn't mind if it needs to be changed to a save window and have the user select the location, but otherwise it can't save directly to the server.

Here is the code that generates the .txt in my controller.

```
$filename = "Payments-".date('d-M-Y').".txt";
        $f = fopen($filename, 'w');
        fwrite($f, $header.PHP_EOL.$payments);
        fclose($f);

        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; ");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

        readfile($filename);

        //exit;

        return view('index')->with('date', $date->format('d-M-y'));
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want the download to happen *as well as* also redirecting the user somewhere? If so, you just simply cannot do this with standard HTTP. However, you *could* do it using a bit of JS. Either: set a session variable for the file to download, and then on redirect inject some JS into the page that 'redirect' the page (using `location.href = 'some-url'` to that URL, or submit the form that generates this download using AJAX and do something similar there.

Answer (score 1):

For redirect:

Use Laravel [redirect](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirects) helper:

```
return redirect('some-url')->with('date', $date->format('d-M-y'));
```

For download file use [enter link description here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#file-downloads) this:

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

Comment: Both seem to do the trick, however I either have the return for the redirect or for the download, any way to overcome this?

Comment: What you want? If you want make redirect to another page - use `redirect()`, or if you want download file - use `download()`

Comment: The idea was to download the file, THEN redirect, but it can't be done because of how HTTP requests works, but the response()->download() saved me some line and headers and I learned something new :P so thanks